# TFS custom widget configuration too small

Tags: tfs, widget, azure-devops, tfs-2015

I am currently building a custom widget for our team project dashboard. My configuration is made of some divs and everything else is being loaded via js. At first you can select your team project and afterwards you get a checkbox for every team in there.

My problem is the iframe above or the div with the class external-content-host. They are fixed to the size 400x150px. I don't know why or how I can fix that. I already tried filling more space with something else at the start and delete it when I need it. Can somebody help me here? The widget is not usable this way.

TFS: 2015U3, 2017, visualstudio.com

Client: Win10, Win8, Win8.1 each Chrome, Edge, IE, Firefox

Versions don't matter.

Comment: Can you provide a minimum reproduction of the issue you're experiencing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the size by call [VSS.resize()](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/reference/client/core-sdk#method_resize) function, but it has the scroll bar. For example, VSS.resize(700,900) (before VSS.notifyLoadSucceeded();).